# JAVA - Looping int numbers?

Tags: java

i want to make a system that creates fake ip adresses (just for fun) but i can't make it work because it doesnt refresh the numbers when i output them in the console. It keeps repeating the same "ip"

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Random IP's");

    Random rand = new Random();

    int randomIp1 = rand.nextInt(999) + 10;
    int randomIp2 = rand.nextInt(999) + 10;
    int randomIp3 = rand.nextInt(999) + 10;
    int randomIp4 = rand.nextInt(999) + 10;

    boolean start = true;

    while (start == true) {
        System.out.println(randomIp1 + "." + randomIp2 + "." + randomIp3 + "." + randomIp4);
    }
}
}
```

keep in mind. I just started learning java so it can be a small change!

Comment: just put the rand.nextInt(999) + 10s in a loop!

Comment: You have no loop there?

Comment: ip addresses go from 1 to 254 ;)

Comment: Sorry i change while to if. But it does only repeat 1 ip instead of diffrent ones

Comment: @FluffyMe you need to put `randomIp1` to `randomIp4` in the loop too

Comment: If you just started learning, it would be a good point to learn to use the debugger of your IDE.

Comment: @Filburt OP wouldn't even need a debugger here. He just needs to actually read __and__ think about what he wrote there.

Comment: @Tom Sometimes it helps having a machine talking reason to oneself. We have all been there I'd guess.

Answer (score 2):

You generate values *once* and then print them out in an infinite loop.

If you want to re-generate the numbers in the loop, then generate them in the loop:

```
while (true) {
    int randomIp1 = rand.nextInt(999) + 10;
    int randomIp2 = rand.nextInt(999) + 10;
    int randomIp3 = rand.nextInt(999) + 10;
    int randomIp4 = rand.nextInt(999) + 10;

    System.out.println(randomIp1 + "." + randomIp2 + "." + randomIp3 + "." + randomIp4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop iterates over the same values over and over again. You never change the current state of the fields, that's why you see always the same number.

```
 while (start == true) {
        System.out.println(randomIp1 + "." + randomIp2 + "." + randomIp3 + "." + randomIp4);
    }
```

In order to fix this you have to reassign the fields *inside* the loop or simply like this:

```
while(true){
 System.out.println(rand.nextInt(999) + "." + rand.nextInt(999) + "." + rand.nextInt(999) + "." + rand.nextInt(999));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this instead. It creates a random between 0 and 0+255.

255 beacuse is the maximun of an IP not 999.

You need to put it in brackets.

```
int randomNumber=(int) (Math.random()*255+0);
```

Use a loop to create as many as you want.